# Parse multipart/related response and save attachment to file

Tags: node.js, mime

I'm doing a simple POST that returns the below. I'm expecting a .txt.gz file. I need to know how to retrieve the attachment. I've tried creating a buffer, delimiting, and splitting before writing the file, but it always comes back as corrupt.

The request library explains how to consume a PUT request for an attachment, but not how to consume a response back.

Can anyone help? Been at this for a week now.

**JSON.stringify(res)**

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            13,
            10,
            45,
            45(..truncated)
        ]
    },
    "headers": {
        "set-cookie": [
            "JSESSIONIDSSO=982EF51351B9497045DB6AB5A2D50DBF; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly",
            "JSESSIONID=995EF8A4A893860159CE463582E4CDDD; Path=/logcollectionservice; Secure; HttpOnly",
            "SoapSession.id=-2851099334472488788"
        ],
        "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
        "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains",
        "content-type": "multipart/related; type=\"text/xml\"; start=\"<852C508C64251E692C9217DFA4EB7433>\"; boundary=\"----=_Part_109_17473961.1526352793275\"",
        "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
        "date": "Tue, 15 May 2018 02:53:13 GMT",
        "connection": "close",
        "server": ""
    },
    "request": {
        "uri": {
            "protocol": "https:",
            "slashes": true,
            "auth": null,
            "host": "50.22.22.22:8443",
            "port": "8443",
            "hostname": "50.22.22.22",
            "hash": null,
            "search": null,
            "query": null,
            "pathname": "/logcollectionservice/services/DimeGetFileService",
            "path": "/logcollectionservice/services/DimeGetFileService",
            "href": "https://50.22.22.22:8443/logcollectionservice/services/DimeGetFileService"
        },
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "Authorization": "Basic YWRt123123123123123123",
            "SOAPAction": "http://schemas.cisco.com/ast/soap/action/#LogCollectionPort#GetOneFile",
            "content-length": 467
        }
    }
}
```

**res.body**

```
------=_Part_183_12814895.1526363698144
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Id: <5DDAB109C3B14685FF6B0EA83D2CF8E4>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body> 
<ns1:GetOneFileResponse 
soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.cisco.com/ast/soap/"><DataHandler 
href="cid:36F92AA211EE04B422D4B07AB07D841A" xsi:type="ns2:DataHandler" 
xmlns:ns2="DimeGetFileService"/></ns1:GetOneFileResponse> 
</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>

------=_Part_183_12814895.1526363698144
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Id: <36F92AA211EE04B422D4B07AB07D841A>

����o�:���W��U����<��퐖.�I��8!h�0�l��?~���m�z��;'����>��oL���'Ϗ��3  
'�tSV�EO�8zÂ���[a0����.��`�4wbO�q��FI���:�n܍>��e- 
��!^@"�U5��;��^����U[V���s˽��q_��̣
����{gm����r��
���c��㬌Pf]Z�����cs���#ߵ� (truncated)

------=_Part_183_12814895.1526363698144--
```

Comment: To be clear: 1. A user selects a file for upload (client js). 2. In your node server you want to read the file. 3. You want to send some kind of feedback to the user when step 2 is done. Your issue happens in step 2 that you cant even read the file (corrupted)?

Comment: I POST to a logcollection API which sends me back the filename in the response, using that filename I then POST to another filecollection API to request the file, which is then sent in that response which I posted here.

Comment: if its node along with http can you simply post your file <buffer or string && mimeType > while letting dependencies manage the compression wrapper/unwrapper. You have the same obj + datatype server side that you worked with on the client

Comment: i'm not posting a file. i'm posting a request for a file, which is sent in the response

Comment: I would really like to help you. However, I still can not understand what you do here and at which point it fails. Could you post a complete demo/example, a short step by step guide and highlight the step where it fails?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/levensailor/fc8849ccbe3271111536015d9e062b7d

Comment: Have you found a suitable solution for your issue? I'm trying to do the same with video files. @JeffLevensailor